# TailWind CSS Dropdown on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following component:

```
<div class="p-5">
    <div class="flex h-64 justify-center">
        <div class="relative ">
            <div class="flex flex-row cursor-pointer truncate p-2 px-4  rounded">
                <div></div>
                <div class="flex flex-row-reverse ml-2 w-full">
                    <div slot="icon" class="relative">
                        <div class="absolute text-xs rounded-full -mt-1 -mr-2 px-1 font-bold top-0 right-0 bg-red-700 text-white">3</div>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-shopping-cart w-6 h-6 mt-2">
                            <circle cx="9" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
                            <circle cx="20" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
                            <path d="M1 1h4l2.68 13.39a2 2 0 0 0 2 1.61h9.72a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.61L23 6H6"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="absolute w-full  rounded-b border-t-0 z-10">
                <div class="shadow-xl w-64">
                    <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100" style="">
                        <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50" alt="img product"></div>
                        <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                            <div class="font-bold">Product 1</div>
                            <div class="truncate">Product 1 description</div>
                            <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                    <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                    <path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                    <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                    <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            $12.22</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100" style="">
                        <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50" alt="img product"></div>
                        <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                            <div class="font-bold">Product 2</div>
                            <div class="truncate">Product 2 long description</div>
                            <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                    <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                    <path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                    <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                    <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            $12.22</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100" style="">
                        <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50" alt="img product"></div>
                        <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                            <div class="font-bold">Product 3</div>
                            <div class="truncate">Product 3 description</div>
                            <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                    <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                    <path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                    <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                    <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            $12.22</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-4 justify-center flex">
                        <button class="text-base  undefined  hover:scale-110 focus:outline-none flex justify-center px-4 py-2 rounded font-bold cursor-pointer 
        hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-teal-100 
        bg-teal-100 
        text-teal-700 
        border duration-200 ease-in-out 
        border-teal-600 transition">Checkout $36.66</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="h-32"></div>
</div>
```

Which looks like:
[The Dropdown Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idkgA.png)
The effect I am looking for is that the dropdown menu firstly is hidden, and each time I hover on the cart logo the dropdown menu will be visible for 2 seconds after leaving the mouse (after the hover finished) from the cart logo.

Answer (score 3):

Added **"group h-0"** class to to parent

```
<div class="relative group h-0 ">
```

So that with the help of it access child class, also make height of parent 0px because don't want parent to take full height when child is hidden,

Then in child **div** First hide the child then add **block** on hover of parent **" hidden group-hover:block"** in **div**

```
 <div class="absolute w-full hidden group-hover:block rounded-b border-t-0 z-10">
```

Hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="p-5">
        <div class="flex h-64 justify-center">
            <div class="relative group h-0 ">
                <div class="flex flex-row cursor-pointer truncate p-2 px-4  rounded">
                    <div></div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row-reverse ml-2 w-full">
                        <div slot="icon" class="relative">
                            <div
                                class="absolute text-xs rounded-full -mt-1 -mr-2 px-1 font-bold top-0 right-0 bg-red-700 text-white">
                                3</div>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-shopping-cart w-6 h-6 mt-2">
                                <circle cx="9" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
                                <circle cx="20" cy="21" r="1"></circle>
                                <path d="M1 1h4l2.68 13.39a2 2 0 0 0 2 1.61h9.72a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.61L23 6H6"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="absolute w-full hidden group-hover:block  rounded-b border-t-0 z-10">
                    <div class="shadow-xl w-64">
                        <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100"
                            style="">
                            <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50"
                                    alt="img product"></div>
                            <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                                <div class="font-bold">Product 1</div>
                                <div class="truncate">Product 1 description</div>
                                <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                                <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                                        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                        <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                        <path
                                            d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2">
                                        </path>
                                        <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                        <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                $12.22
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100"
                            style="">
                            <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50"
                                    alt="img product"></div>
                            <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                                <div class="font-bold">Product 2</div>
                                <div class="truncate">Product 2 long description</div>
                                <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                                <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                                        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                        <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                        <path
                                            d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2">
                                        </path>
                                        <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                        <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                $12.22
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-100"
                            style="">
                            <div class="p-2 w-12"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bababa/0011ff&amp;text=50x50"
                                    alt="img product"></div>
                            <div class="flex-auto text-sm w-32">
                                <div class="font-bold">Product 3</div>
                                <div class="truncate">Product 3 description</div>
                                <div class="text-gray-400">Qt: 2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex-col w-18 font-medium items-end">
                                <div class="w-4 h-4 mb-6 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-full cursor-pointer text-red-700">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                                        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 ">
                                        <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                                        <path
                                            d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2">
                                        </path>
                                        <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                                        <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                $12.22
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-4 justify-center flex">
                            <button class="text-base  undefined  hover:scale-110 focus:outline-none flex justify-center px-4 py-2 rounded font-bold cursor-pointer 
            hover:bg-teal-700 hover:text-teal-100 
            bg-teal-100 
            text-teal-700 
            border duration-200 ease-in-out 
            border-teal-600 transition">Checkout $36.66</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="h-32"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).